# How does Laravel know which session to take?

Tags: php, laravel, session

I'm using Laravel Session in my project. It works, files are added to storage/framework/sessions. But there are a lot of files with different names and random letters. How does Laravel know which session to take for user? How does Laravel know which file is which? This information is in laravel_session?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Session is same as PHP Sessions but used in a different way (or syntax to be precise).
whenever you create a session, it creates a file on the server with a cookie on the browser with the file name of the particular session.

Comment: But i don't see any cookies in my browser except laravel_session.

Comment: thats where the filename is stored.

Comment: where PHP uses `PHPSESSID`  laravel uses `laravel_session`

Comment: Ok, so it's laravel_session. Thank you so much!